# Google maps shows blank page in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am not a programmer but am doing a very basic android development app through work.

I have managed to set up all the config keys in order to get a google map screen in my app up and running. However, when I click to open the map screen it shows a blank map (only showing a google logo at the bottom of my screen).

I have looked at questions from people here with similar issue, so I suspect I need to add certain permissions in my android manifest and also play a bit with my java code? So really hoping someone would be able to look into my code and point me to the right direction (kind of baby steps...)

Thanks

**Android Manifest xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.learn5things">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LocationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CultureActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FoodActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FootballActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CarnavalActivity" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity maps (XML)**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.learn5things.MapsActivity" />
```

**Maps Activity (java file)**

```
    package com.example.android.learn5things;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Brazil and move the camera
        LatLng brazil = new LatLng(-8.892710, -56.098682);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(brazil).title("Marker in Brazil"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(brazil));

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an obtained key in 'google_maps_key' value ? Check res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to clarify Google Play Services version in your manifest.xml file under application tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also, I think your google maps api key should be referenced as:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Also, make sure you put your actual Google Maps Key in your strings file!
Hope it helped.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#get_a_google_maps_api_key)

Comment: Thanks Arunce for your help! I managed to find in the error log that there was some issue with my API key. So I went into Google developer and generated a new one and this seem to have solved the problem. I have not yet tried to implement your suggestions as it seems to be working as expected now, but I might go and updated it later and see if anything else changes? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yeah that happened to me once as well, no problem :)